# Mysql select match and unmatched records from two different tables by comparing more then two columns

Tags: mysql

### system Table

```
id sys_id  sys_date  sys_load
-- ------ ---------- --------
1   4472  2017-09-06  500000
2   5678  2017-09-06  300000
3   4323  2017-09-06  400000
4   8976  2017-09-06  200000
5   8976  2017-09-06  0
6   9890  2017-09-06  0
7   9890  2017-09-06  100000
8   9999  2017-09-06  200000
9   4472  2017-09-05  100000
10  5678  2017-09-05  900000
```

### man Table

```
id man_id  man_date  man_load
-- ------ ---------- --------
1   4472  2017-09-06  500000
2   5678  2017-09-06  300000
3   4323  2017-09-06  400000
4   8976  2017-09-06  200000
5   9890  2017-09-06  100000
```

1.I want to select records from system table by matching sys_id,sys_date,sys_load with man table man_id,man_date,man_load.
 date comes from front end.

```
select sys_id
     , sys_load 
  from system
     , man 
 where DATE(sys_date) = '2017-09-06' 
   and man_date = '2017-09-06' 
   and sys_id = man_id 
   and sys_load = man_load_amt 
 order 
    by sys_id;
```

gives me the expected result like below

```
1   4472  2017-09-06  500000
2   5678  2017-09-06  300000
3   4323  2017-09-06  400000
4   8976  2017-09-06  200000
5   9890  2017-09-06  100000
```

is the above query is good or any wrong in it?

2.Now i want to select the records from system table which are not matching with the above result set for the date '2017-09-06'.
i.e,

```
id sys_id  sys_date  sys_load
-- ------ ---------- --------
5   8976  2017-09-06  0
6   9890  2017-09-06  0
8   9999  2017-09-06  200000
```

note: ids 8976 and 9890 have two entries. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well, three observations: 1. We stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us. 2. Once you rewrite the query the correct way, the answer to your problem will become trivial. 3. Functions cannot use indexes so, assuming you index sys_date, then you may want to rethink how that comparison works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get rid of old styled joins. Please use explicit join syntax -

1 - For matching records

```
select sys_id
      ,sys_load 
from system
inner join man on sys_id = man_id 
where DATE(sys_date) = '2017-09-06' 
and man_date = '2017-09-06' 
and sys_load = man_load_amt 
order by sys_id;`
```

Edit - **I have just noticed you have unmatched records in system also. So you need left join rather than inner**

2 - For un-matching records

```
select sys_id
      ,sys_load 
from system
left join man on sys_id = man_id 
where DATE(sys_date) = '2017-09-06' 
and (sys_load <> man_load or man_load is null)
order by sys_id;
```

Comment: I am sorry but after this you have to help me out as i have no idea what is wrong with this query?

Comment: I have checked it on rextester. The result was same as expected.

Comment: Well, we'd normally write that this way `SELECT s.id
     , s.sys_id
     , s.sys_load 
  FROM system s
  LEFT 
  JOIN man m
    ON s.sys_id   = m.man_id
   AND m.man_date = s.sys_date
   AND m.man_load = s.sys_load 
 WHERE s.sys_date = '2017-09-06'
   AND m.id IS NULL
 ORDER 
    BY s.sys_id;` - Now, your query may be functionally identical to that, but I'm not a sufficiently competent logician to say.